# Is defining map always a submersion? Why?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Is local defining map always a submersion? Why?

I came up with this issue in some part of my proof for other things.. This might be a stupid question, but thank you guys for your help in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by a "defining map"?

Comment: @TedShifrin sorry it should be local defining map. According to page 107 of John M. Lee's Introduction to Differential Manifold.

Comment: sorry I am really bad at latex, I will try typing it up later

Comment: Without a lot more context, including definitions, it's pretty much impossible to make any sense out of this question.

Comment: Well I can answer, but my answer is based on my proof of other things.

Answer (score 4):

You can probably answer your own question if you just work backwards through the definitions in the book. On page 107, I define a ***local defining map*** for a submanifold $S\subseteq M$ as "a smooth map $\Phi\colon U\to N$ such that $S\cap U$ is a regular level set of $\Phi$" (where $U$ is an open subset of $M$). Then if you look back at the top of page 106, I defined a ***regular level set*** of $\Phi$ to be a subset of the form $\Phi^{-1}(c)$ (shorthand for $\Phi^{-1}(\{c\})$) where $c$ is a regular value of $\Phi$. A little before that, I said "$c$ is a ***regular value*** of $\Phi$ if every point of the level set $\Phi^{-1}(c)$ is a regular point."  And back a few lines further, "a point $p\in M$ is said to be a ***regular point*** of $\Phi$ if $d\Phi_p\colon T_pM \to T_{\Phi(p)}N$ is surjective."

Once you've found all those definitions, I recommend that you go back to the book and read them in forward order, taking some time to absorb each definition as you read it. There are a lot of definitions being layered on top of each other here, so you shouldn't feel bad if you don't instantly grasp them the first time you read them.

The upshot is that what's being assumed when we talk about a "local defining map" is that $d\Phi_p$ is surjective at each point $p\in S\cap U$. To say $\Phi$ is a submersion would mean that $d\Phi_p$ is surjective at *every* point $p$ in the domain of $\Phi$. So the answer is no, a local defining map need not be a submersion.

Here's a simple counterexample. Let $S$ be the unit circle in $\mathbb R^2$. The map $\Phi\colon \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ given by $\Phi(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ is a local defining map for $S$ (actually a global one in this case, but every global defining map is also a local defining map). But it's not a submersion because its differential vanishes at the origin.

Comment: Well, then, why make the domain too large? :)

Comment: @TedShifrin: Of course, you don't have to. But the point of defining it the way I did is that it's handy to be able to refer to the function $\Phi$ in my example as a defining function for the circle, without having to fuss with redefining it's domain.